# search of segments that form an angle with HoughLinesP and c++

Tags: c++, opencv, houghlinesp

I want to call a function to compare all of the segments that I calculate in my code and know how many polygons there are in my view, made up of straight lines, which consist of 3, 4 or more segments that form a closed path, or alternatively i would like to know how many pairs of straight segments form an angle (thus have a common point):

```
           vector<Vec4i> lines;
       HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 80, 50, 10 );
       for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
           {
           Vec4i l = lines[i];
           double x = l[0]-l[2];
           double y = l[1]-l[3];
           double dist = pow(x,2) + pow(y,2);
           dist= sqrt(dist);
           segments.push_back(round(dist));
           line( cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
           }
```

alternatvely, trying to simplify, how can i calculate the number of intersections between segments?

Comment: The image you used to compute Hough would helpful

Comment: basically I have to detect the geometric features in the images . I would like to be able to calculate for example the number of windows within an image , then I consider a window as a polygon composed of 4 segments that form a closed path

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, given a polygon you want to know how many vertices it has.

I think a nice option is to use [cv::approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c&gsc.tab=0), which will give you the minimum number of vertices needed to represent your polygon. According to the number of vertices, you can classify the polygons.

You can look at [pyImageSerach](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) blog for a good tutorial (in Python).